# Adding a DividerItemDecoration on top of the element

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to add a divider on top of my element in a RecyclerView.

Following google i've succeded to add a DividerItemDecoration, the code is as below:

**DividerItemDecoration:**

```
public class DividerItemDecoration extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

private static final int[] ATTRS = new int[]{
        android.R.attr.listDivider
};

public static final int HORIZONTAL_LIST = LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL;
public static final int VERTICAL_LIST = LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL;
private Drawable mDivider;
private int mOrientation;

public DividerItemDecoration(Context context, int orientation) {
    final TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(ATTRS);
    mDivider = a.getDrawable(0);
    a.recycle();
    setOrientation(orientation);
}

public void setOrientation(int orientation) {
    if (orientation != HORIZONTAL_LIST && orientation != VERTICAL_LIST) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid orientation");
    }
    mOrientation = orientation;
}

@Override
public void onDrawOver(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    if (mOrientation == VERTICAL_LIST) {
        drawVertical(c, parent);
    } else {
        drawHorizontal(c, parent);
    }
}

public void drawVertical(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
    final int left = parent.getPaddingLeft();
    final int right = parent.getWidth() - parent.getPaddingRight();

    final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        final RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child
                .getLayoutParams();
        final int top = child.getBottom() + params.bottomMargin;
        final int bottom = top + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
        mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        mDivider.draw(c);
    }
}

public void drawHorizontal(Canvas c, RecyclerView parent) {
    final int top = parent.getPaddingTop();
    final int bottom = parent.getHeight() - parent.getPaddingBottom();

    final int childCount = parent.getChildCount();
    for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
        final View child = parent.getChildAt(i);
        final RecyclerView.LayoutParams params = (RecyclerView.LayoutParams) child
                .getLayoutParams();
        final int left = child.getRight() + params.rightMargin;
        final int right = left + mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight();
        mDivider.setBounds(left, top, right, bottom);
        mDivider.draw(c);
    }
}

@Override
public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
    if (mOrientation == VERTICAL_LIST) {
        outRect.set(0, 0, 0, mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight());
    } else {
        outRect.set(0, 0, mDivider.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0);
    }
}
}
```

**The result:**

[image: DividerItemDecoration]

**What i'm trying to accomplish:**

[image: DividerItemDecorationResult]

I've tried to play with the offset and the index but didn't get expected result.

How can I add the same item divider on top of my elements?

Also in case of necessary i've leave my layout of the row, here is the code:

**Row:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescrizione"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBarcode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvDescrizione"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvDescrizione"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I assume Your button and textViews are on the same view. So use another view's type for button. That's it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Explanation : In this answer i have added a divider above every item in your RecyclerView and after the RecyclerView itself. This way you wont have "overdraw", where 2 lines are painted on top of each other.I have used View tag for this purpose which draws a simple line from the xml.

**Row file :**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <View android:layout_height="2dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescrizione"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBarcode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvDescrizione"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvDescrizione"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Main file :**

```
<LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/repository_rv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:listitem="@layout/tmp3"
            android:layout_marginTop="30dp"/>

        <View
            android:id="@+id/bottomLine"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"/>

 </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is the difference between doing this and the first answer?

Comment: @G.Ciardini: This answer adds a divider above every item in your `RecyclerView` and after the `RecyclerView` itself. This way you wont have "overdraw", where 2 lines are painted on top of each other.

Comment: @VishvaDave: If you explain why your solution answers the question, you also get my upvote.

Comment: @hamena314 :) thanks for explanation.. actually i was expecting self explanation from my code.. and my code worked you got it right.. that's enough :) :)

Comment: Actually I found your code to be self-explanatory enough to understand it. But it is still nice to have a comment / short explanation to see how this helps at a glance. Still upvoted. :)

Comment: @VishvaDave is right. it is working well as per your need. if item divider can be added from row layout then why you need to add DividerItemDecoration class in your code. Your motive is just to add divider before item and its added using row layout. Then what will be the better explanation you need guys .:)

Comment: Thank you so much both of you for appreciation :) Happy coding :)

Comment: @VishvaDave Thanks for the explanations, by the way i know how to choose the answer no need to reminder. I was just waiting for see if other choice come out. But your code work perfect thanks again. ;)

Comment: @G.Ciardini if my answer had solved your issue then why have you changed mark? is there any query? you can ask

Comment: @VishvaDave I changed the mark because with your view (in the main file) is placed under the recyclerview. Sorry if i didn't comment or anything, that was my bad.

Comment: yes that is because i thaught you want a line before an item and after the item.. so if you don't want a line after the last item then remove the line from there... also in previous answer you will have double over drawn lines you can see in your output you will have thick line in between the items and thin line at last...but its your choice how you want an output so no issues...happy coding

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste `DividerItemDecoration` and change the following two lines. I only tested for vertical orientation.

```
//Change - getItemOffsets
//old 
outRect.set(0, 0, 0, mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight())
//new
outRect.set(0, mDivider.getIntrinsicHeight(), 0, 0)

//Change - drawVertical
//old
final int bottom = mBounds.bottom + Math.round(child.getTranslationY())
//new
final int bottom = mBounds.bottom + Math.round(child.getTranslationY()) - child.getHeight()
```

Answer (score -3):

Don't add divider via Item Decoration. Instead put Two vies above and below of your row code like below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="Vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
<View 
   android:layout_height="1px"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:background="#000000"
   />
<RelativeLayout 
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content">

 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvDescrizione"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvBarcode"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvDescrizione"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvData"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvDescrizione"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:textSize="18sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
<View android:layout_height="1px"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:background="#000000"
  />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what is the main difference between doing that and the second answer?

Comment: @G.Ciardini: This answer adds a divider-line above and below an item in your `RecyclerView`. Seems like you would have some "overdraw" where one line gets painted over another.

Comment: Basically the below-divider of the first item is overdrawn by the above-divider of the second item.